# Should onCaptureCompleted method be called continuously?

Tags: android, camera2

my camera(camera2 api) eats so much from battery and device is being hot after 5 minutes running. During trying to find out where is the problem, i saw that `onCaptureCompleted` method of `CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback` is being called continuously when preview is in running state. Is it normal ?

Answer (score 0):

If you call `setRepeatingRequest()` then it is normal to get multiple call in `onCaptureCompleted()`. If you want a single shot you can replace `setRepeatingRequest()` with `capture()` .

And the number of time `onCaptureCompleted()` called is depend on things like capture request's template type.